# Aligning half line to the left and the second to the right in CoreText

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-text

I am creating a Point-of-Sale (POS) receipt and need to have item names with a certain width and need to have a price on the right (like `float-right` in `CSS`).

I am using https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTCoreText to create the content. Any ideas how to achieve this without having to create two views and place them on top of each other?

Just to clarify, I need to have this:

```
Coffee                  £1.45
   milk, skinny
Danish Pastry           £1.75
Coca Cola               £1.10
Full English Bfst      £12.50
```

So pretty much I need a string to be floating on the left and other string floating on the right ...

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that without having two objects, one with left alignment and one with right alignment. Even CSS would require two objects to achieve this.

Comment: we need 2 objects either in HTML & CSS or our native code. I agree with @BrianShamblen. Best thing is go for web view with HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is inserting in each string f.e. 30 spaces after the first string and assigning wordWrap = truncate middle. Not so sure that this is exactly what you're looking for.

I agree with Brian Shamblen it'l be pretty easy to do with 2 labels.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want isn't really a second column, which Core Text cannot do out of the box, but rather a tabular layout (like good ol' `<table>`). Fortunately tabular layout can be acheived in Core Text by using tab stops. The only 2 things you need are:

- the `CHARACTER TABULATION` (`U+0009`) character,
- and a paragraph style with the correct tab stops setting.

That can be done this way:

```
NSString *string = @"Coffee\t£1.45\n  milk, skinny\nDanish Pastry\t£1.75\nCoca Cola\t£1.10\nFull English Bfst\t£12.50";
CGFloat width = 200;

NSArray *tabs = @[CFBridgingRelease(CTTextTabCreate(kCTTextAlignmentRight, width, NULL))];
CTParagraphStyleSetting setting = {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierTabStops, sizeof(tabs), &tabs};
CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(&setting, 1);
NSDictionary *attributes = @{CFBridgingRelease(kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName): CFBridgingRelease(paragraphStyle)};
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];
```

There are two caveats:

- You need to know the width of the view when creating the paragraph style.
- Core Text won't wrap lines on tab stops which means you have to make sure your text is short enough to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do the following with just one `UILabel` per line:

- Define a left word like "Coffee" and a right one like "£1.45".
- Make a string by concatenating the left word with a space and the
  right one.
- Define the `width` and `height` of the frame that you want the label with that
  string to be contained in, with `CGSizeMake(width, height)`.
- Estimate the size of that label using `sizeThatFits` providing the
  `CGSize` constraints that you want as an argument.
- If the estimated width of the label is smaller than the required
  width, increase the size of your label, by adding a space to your
  string and repeat.

In code:

```
NSArray *leftWords = @[@"Coffee", @"    milk, skinny", @"Danish Pastry", @"Coca Cola", @"Full English Bfst"];
    NSArray *rightWords = @[@"£1.45", @"", @"£1.75", @"£1.10", @"£12.50"];

    CGFloat xOffset = 5;
    CGFloat yOffset = 60;
    CGFloat labelHeight = 44;
    CGFloat labelWidth = 300;

    for (int i = 0; i < leftWords.count; i ++) {

        UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset + i * labelHeight, labelWidth, labelHeight)];
        aLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        aLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        aLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        aLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

        NSString *leftWord = [leftWords objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *rightWord = [rightWords objectAtIndex:i];
        NSMutableString *spaces = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@" "];

        const CGFloat MAX_WIDTH = 310;
        CGSize maxLabelSize = CGSizeMake(MAX_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX);

        CGSize expectedSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        CGFloat expectedWidth = 0.0;

        NSString *phrase = @"";
        do {
            phrase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", leftWord, spaces, rightWord];
            aLabel.text = phrase;
            expectedSize = [aLabel sizeThatFits:maxLabelSize];
            expectedWidth = expectedSize.width;
            // Increase spaces
            [spaces appendString:@" "];

        } while (expectedWidth < MAX_WIDTH);

        CGRect frame = aLabel.frame;
        frame.size = expectedSize;
        aLabel.frame = frame;

        [self.view addSubview:aLabel];
    }
```

I have placed the above within my `viewDidLoad` and did `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to allow marking of the border of the UILabel.

Here is a screenshot of my working code:

[image]

It works for the "milk, skinny" line too as the text alignment of the label is set to `NSTextAlignmentLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem and found no answers.. so I created a class for anyone that needs it! Let's say you want to create a list of strings like the example in the question:

```
- (void)createReceipt {

    NSString *coffee = [LRString LRStringWithLeft:@"Coffee" right:@"£1.45" maxlength:29 maxleft:16 maxright:11];

}
```

This "coffee" string would look like this:

```
Coffee                  £1.45
```

"maxlength" is the maximum length of your string
"maxleft" is the maximum length of your left string (coffee)
"maxright" is the maximum length of your right string (price)

If the name exceeds the "maxleft" length, then the last 3 letters of the name (coffee) will be replaced with "..."

Check it out on GitHub here: https://github.com/iosdec/LRString